# MacTex typeset button disappeared

Tags: installing, mac

After removing old version of TeXlive and install the recent one, typeset button disappeared so that I cannot do anything. Would you help me out?
[image]

Comment: TeXLive is a distribution and you're having trouble with an editor. What editor is this? Have you tried updating the editor to the latest version?

Comment: TexShop what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `Command-T` (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). But, if you want the button back, starting with

[image]

Go to `Windows/Customize Toolbar...`

[image]

Drag the `Typset` button to the toolbar...

[image]

Comment: oh thanks but after quitting the program then it disappears again how can I fix it?

Comment: @Jimmy: I really don't know. I would recommend you reinstall TeXShop.

Comment: What versions of MacOS, TeXShop and MacTeX/TeX Live are you using?

Comment: @Jimmy: I think Herb's comment was meant for you. I am using MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6) and TeXShop 4.15.